# How to assign a directory / path / folder with a space in the name to a Bash variable?

Tags: bash, terminal

How can I add a path with a space in a Bash variable in `.bashrc`? I want to store some variables in `.bashrc` for paths and I encountered a path with a space in it.

I tried to add it between `' '` or use the escape character `\`, but it didn't help:

```
games=/run/media/mohamedRadwan/games\ moves    # this doesn't work
games='/run/media/mohamedRadwan/games  moves'  # or this
games="/run/media/mohamedRadwan/games  moves"  # or this
```

... when I run:

```
mount $games
```

... it throws an error indicating that it's only trying to mount `/run/media/mohamedRadwan/games`.

But when I run `echo $games`, it shows the full value, `/run/media/mohamedRadwan/games moves`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Always, always, always quote variable de-references: `echo "$games"`

Comment: (...except when your variable contains a pattern or regex and is on the right-hand side of a comparison or `=~` in `[[ ]]` ;) )

Comment: @BenjaminW.: You don't need `"` in `[[` at all.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Or you just any case in which you want it to subject to shell rules.

Comment: @choroba You do if you want a literal match

Comment: It should have been "almost ever", not "at all".

Comment: @bishop the problem with me not echo statement it  when write **mount $games** in .bashrc file it make error because it found the path  just /run/media/mohamedRadwan/games  without moves

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
mount /dev/sda9 "$games"
```

As mentioned, always quote variable dereferences. Otherwise, the shell confuses the spaces in the variable's value as spaces separating multiple values.

Answer (score 5):

When variable contains spaces, variable expansion and then word splitting will result to many arguments,  echo command will display all arguments but other program or function may handle arguments another way.

Surrounding variable with double quotes will prevent arguments to be splitted

```
printf "'%s'\n" $games

printf "'%s'\n" "$games"
```